# Azure Functions V2 Http Error Code content not returned when function published

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working with Azure Functions V2, developing in Visual Studio 2017. I want to return custom content for the HTTP error codes my function returns. This works fine when I test locally. But when I publish the function to Azure, the custom content is no longer returned.

This is easy to reproduce. Here's a function (distilled down from the VS 2017  Azure Function new project template):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("StatusCodeTest")]
        public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            return new NotFoundObjectResult("Sample content text.");
        }
    }
}
```

Run locally and issue a Post or Get from Postman. It will return a 404 Not Found status code and display a response body of "Sample content text."

Publish the function to Azure and invoke it there --either by Postman or using the Test or Run feature of the Azure Portal. 404 is still returned, but the custom output is replaced by a generic message, "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Same behavior for other *...ObjectResult* status codes, such as BadRequestObjectResult, etc.

How can I publish or configure my function so that it returns the custom error status content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a regression in the latest Functions v2 runtime (2.0.11888). Please see https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/117 for more details and workaround.

More generally, please follow this repo to make sure you get all notifications.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I had not come across that repo or post. Will follow it here on out. As with so many things Microsoft, there's an overwhelming amount of information, docs, sources to sift through. I'm really enjoying the serverless function dev experience. We're building out a production app using Azure Funcitons and it's going very well. Definitely sold on the technology and ease of use.

Comment: Is there any eta regarding azure functions v2 ?

Comment: No exact ETA, but it's not too far out now. Follow that repo to stay up to date